Azure Web App Processing of Service Bus Queues Is Slow C#
We are updating our SaaS application messaging processes. We currently store and recall our internal application messages from an SQL database; we are moving to Service Bus queues.
We have an Azure Web App to receive, process, and complete the messages in the queues. This works, but we are finding trade-offs that compromise performance or cause exceptions in the underlying Service Bus SDK. We need to process roughly 400k messages a day.
I've reproduced our issues in the code snippet below.

Currently using the code below, the processing of messages from the
queue is slow while it waits for the last message to complete before
moving to the next message. We are not processing messages fast enough to keep up with peak message creation. Using this code, we are processing roughly 1000 in 5 minutes.

If we replace receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message).Wait();
with receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
An exception was raised per the message we processed. The messages are processed (in our app) and completed in the queue - but Application Insights shows hundreds of thousands of exceptions. Presumably because we're disposing of the receiver before it has fully completed.



A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task
or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved
exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. The lock supplied is
invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been
removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver
instance.


If we don't dispose of the receiver and client, the web app's connections and memory will increase. Nothing will be released, and the web app will fall over.

How can we correctly dispose of the client and receiver, complete the message without raising exceptions and achieve the performance we are looking for?
    internal void Listen()
    {
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(_host);
        ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queue, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
        {
            SubQueue = SubQueue.None,
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock
        });
        
        IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> messages = receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(fetchCount, wait).Result;

        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Body + " " + message.LockedUntil);

                //This causes exceptions when the receiver is disposed
                    // receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
                
                //this is slower to process
                receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
        }

        //if we don't dispose, the connections and memory use in the web app will increase to breaking point. 
        receiver.DisposeAsync();
        client.DisposeAsync();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


Have you thought of using await? .Wait() is a blocking call. You have a strange combination of blocking code mixed with unawaited task based dispose methods. It seems you don't fully understand async/await. Can you explain a bit more about the choices you made?

@Damo Try switching to await instead of .Wait() for all async calls, and ensure proper resource reuse by reusing the client and receiver instead of disposing of them after every batch.

As Peter stated, you're using sync-over-async, which is a known anti-pattern known to cause thread pool starvation and deadlocks.   The Service Bus client library was intentionally written to be used asynchronously.   Attempting to block is as you are with .Result and .Wait is not recommended and will have a non-trivial impact on throughput.
